# copy the middle of 2dim array into another array

Tags: visual-c++

I want to copy the middle of  2dim array into another array. who knows how i can do it.
for example I have:

```
int A[4][2] = {{1, 2} ,{5, 6} , {7, 8} , {3, 4} };
```

copy the second and third rows into another array to have the following array:

```
int B[4][2] = {{null, null} ,{5, 6} , {7, 8} , {null, null} };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [**`Array::Copy Method (Array, Int32, Array, Int32, Int32)`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

> Copies a range of elements from an Array starting at the specified source index and pastes them to another Array starting at the specified destination index. The length and the indexes are specified as 32-bit integers.

Comment: I used namespace std in the top of my main program have can i use namespace system?